# MapStruct : Mapping a object property to an upper level object

Tags: java, mapstruct, object-object-mapping

Consider the below classes

```
class ContributionDoc {
  private String contributorName;
  private String version;
  private int contributionNumber;
  private List<Contribution> contributions;
}
```

```
class Contribution {
  private String metadata;
}
```

Class ContributionDoc needs to be mapped to class ContributionDocDto.
Class Contribution needs to be mapped to class ContributionDetails.

```
class ContributionEntity {
  private String contributorName;
  private int contributionNumber;
}
```

Both class ContributionDocDto and ContributionDetails have ContributionEntity (because we later realized that ContributionEntity needs to be moved from ContributionDocDto to ContributionDetails)

```
class ContributionDocDto {
  private ContributionEntity;
  private String docVersion;
  private List<Contribution> contributions;
}
```

```
class ContributionDetails {
  private ContributionEntity;
  private String metadata;
}
```

I have below mappers with usual annotations from mapstruct

```
ContributionDocDto map (ContributionDoc doc)
```

```
ContributionDetails map (Contribution contrib)
```

How can I populate an instance of ContributionEntity inside ContributionDetails ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide more meaningful classes? I am having really hard time understanding what needs to be mapped to what. Single letter classes with random letters of the alphabet is really difficult to understand.

Comment: @Filip thanks for your reply. I've edited the question

Comment: Take a look at this [Mapping nested bean properties to current target](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-nested-bean-properties-to-current-target)

Comment: Not sure how it can be done. In my case, I need to map a nested bean property to its container bean

Comment: What is the source for `ContributionEnity`? (note there's no field, only a class)? The source object only has a `metadata` attribute..